# Why not using pip install?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I own a debian/ubuntu vps and lots of people advise me to not use `sudo pip install ...` to install Python modules. Unfortunately, lots of packages are not available through `apt-get install python-...` and worse it is much harder to find the package's name. https://pypi.python.org/pypi is very convenient for both installing the latest stable release and look for packages.

So I am lost because according to sysadmin I MUST not use `pip install`, but majority of packages recommend to use `pip` to install them.

What precaution should I make to use `pip` properly? For example I had an issue with my `umask` that was set to `027` and installed packages through `sudo pip install ...` weren't usable because the user couldn't access the installed packages.

At last, lots of people also advise to use `virtualenv`, but this is not a suitable solution for permanent installations and it is not convenient to install the virtualenv at each login.

Comment: Perhaps they simply advice against it because you give root access (`sudo ...`) or because you install the package globally. A more elegant solution can be to install `pip install --user ...` or create an environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt anyone is telling you not to use `pip`. You *should* be using it.

I suspect the advice is warning against the use of `sudo`. You should not be installing libraries globally; rather, you should create a virtualenv for each project, and install things locally inside it, which doesn't require `sudo`.

virtualenv is perfectly suitable for "permanent installations" - I have no idea why you would think it wouldn't be. If having to activate your virtualenv each time is really too much of a hassle, you could look into virtualenvwrapper.